# SSH key injection in openstack

Tags: openstack, cloud-init

During vm creation in openstack, one can specify a keypair name, so that the specified public key get injected to the newly created vm.

I would like to know in which state of machine the key injection is done, completely? Given the machine is in ACTIVE state, does that guarantee that the key injection is completed?

**Details**: 
I have a limited quota for the key pairs and I would like to delete  each keypair from openstack immediately after they get injected to the target machine. I have only access to openstack ReST API and NOT to the target vm.

**UPDATE**
Looking at nova ***instances*** table, I can see that "key name" and "key data" are existing there too. I think the key is copied to this table and then the original key is not referenced any more. So deleting the key shouldn't cause any issue. am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is try a ssh connection and once that succeeds, proceed to delete the keypair.

To answer your question directly, the key is added via the cloud-init. You can grep for ssh in /var/log/cloud-init.log to see when exactly it happens. (It happens pretty early in the cloud-init process).

I don't think there is any API way of figuring out when exactly the key injection happens. Machine in ACTIVE state is not a guarantee that cloud-init part of key injection is done (though for practical purposes, it does happen pretty early).

You could try checking it via nova console-log. Though the output of console-log has limited buffer, so it may overshoot the key addition part and hence you may not see it in console log.

So, I think checking via actual ssh connection is the only sure shot way.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, ssh to target vm is not an option. I have tested some sample images with two consequent ReST call, first one to create vm and then immediately the second one to delete the keypair and in all test cases the key was injected to the vm, but I didn't find any document to guarantee the same behavior for all images.

Comment: The key injection is part of the cloud-init rather than of openstack. But I think you can safely assume that once vm is running, it has got the key.

Comment: just an unrelated FYI - In case of non-related failures (if metadata get fails), your vm might end up without the keys